# Return D3 key of Selected

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I know I can use `d3.keys()` to return all keys inside of an object, but I want to return the selected items key I'm targeting inside of a mouseover event.

I'm targeting elements in D3 like so:

```
var test = something.selectAll('rect')
    .data(myData['groupSelection'])
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .on('mouseover', function (d) {
        console.log(d3.keys(d));
    }
```

This will return **that** given selections keys though, when I really need a count of that items keys, for instance, if I select the second rect created from the data, it'd be nice for it to return 2.

Comment: `.on('mouseover', function(d, i) { console.log(i + 1); });`?

Comment: What's it doing with the d element passed in?

Comment: Nothing. You just want the index, right?

Comment: Yes. Didn't realize it would be that simple. So anytime d3 sees function(d) it automatically know to loop through all data sets?  If you put that in an answer I'll gladly accept it for what it is.

Comment: Just to clarify: it doesn't loop through the data sets at the time of the event, it creates a different event handler for each object with its index at the time you call the `on` method (if you deleted elements later you'd need to re-assign the event handler to get the updated index values).  But I'll let @LarsKotthoff post the full answer version.

Comment: That information will be very helpful in the future. Than you @AmeliaBR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All callbacks in D3 that get the data as an argument also get the index of the data as an argument. That is, instead of

```
.attr("foo", function(d) { ... });
```

you can also write

```
.attr("foo", function(d, i) { ... });
```

where `d` is the data and `i` the index of `d` in the array of data that you've passed to `.data()`. The same goes for `.style()`, `.on()`, etc.

For example, assume you have data `[2,3]` and elements with data `1` and `2` bound to them. Now if you do (note the key function to `.data()` to match elements by their contents)

```
var sel = d3.selectAll("element").data([2,3], function(d) { return d; });
```

you'll get non-empty enter (containing 3), update (containing 2) and exit (containing the element that 1 was bound to) selections. You can operate on each of these selections, e.g.

```
sel.attr("foo", function(d, i) { ... });
```

The `i` refers to the index within the selection. Each selection contains only one element, so you'll get 0 for `i` -- for each selection. That is, the code

```
sel.attr("foo", function(d, i) { console.log(i); });
sel.enter().attr("foo", function(d, i) { console.log(i); });
sel.exit().attr("foo", function(d, i) { console.log(i); });
```

will log 0 to the console three times. If your update selection was of length 3 for example (that is, three elements in the argument to `.data()` are matched up with DOM elements in the selection), you would get 0, 1, 2 on the console.

Comment: Is there other arguments to d3 available aside from the index and data?

Comment: Yes, if you have nested selections, there's a third argument that will give you the index of the data item in the parent selection.